# java.lang.ClassCastException when command runs. Everything works correctly, internal error occurred message

Tags: java, bukkit

Error: INFO Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ShlobdonG.gMarry.Commands cannot be cast to org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin

Code:

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("vmarry")) {
    if (!(player == null)) {
        if (!player.hasPermission("gmarry.marry")) {
            sender.sendMessage("You can't marry a player because of permission!");
            return true;
        } else {

            int cooldown = this.plugin.getConfig().getInt(
                    "request-cooldown");
            if (this.plugin.vmarry.containsKey(player.getName())) {
                long diff = (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.plugin.vmarry
                        .get(sender.getName())) / 1000;
                if (diff < cooldown) {
                    player.sendMessage("You must wait "
                            + cooldown
                            + " seconds before marrying another player.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (args.length > 0) {
            final Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(
                    args[0]);
            long keepAlive = this.plugin.getConfig().getLong(
                    "keep-alive") * 20;

            if (target == null) {
                sender.sendMessage("You can only marry players that are online!");
                return false;
            }
            if (target == player) {
                sender.sendMessage("You can't bite yourself!");
                return false;
            }

            sendRequest(player, target);

            Bukkit.getServer()
                    .getScheduler()
                    .scheduleSyncDelayedTask((Plugin) this,
                            new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    killRequest(target.getName());
                                }
                            }, keepAlive);

            this.plugin.vmarry.put(player.getName(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
        } else {
            player.sendMessage("Attempt to marry player..");
            player.sendMessage("/vmarry <player>");
        }
    }
}
```

I realize the code is messy but where is the issue that causes ClassCatException? I'm lost...

```
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO ... 15 more
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at com.ShlobdonG.gMarry.Commands.onCommand(Commands.java:182) ~[?:?]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ShlobdonG.gMarry.Commands cannot be cast to org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:574) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:675) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:399) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:739) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:46) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_111]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_111]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1179) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1344) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:650) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-6854dee-dbf4ecf]
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] INFO org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'vmarry' in plugin gMarry v1.0
10.02 22:41:50 [Server] ERROR null
```

Comment: The stacktrace contains a line number for your code. Please show it and tell us what line it is

Comment: https://paste.md-5.net/rogimiqalo.vbs

Comment: `Commands.java` line 182... What does it (and the surrounding code) say?

Comment: .scheduleSyncDelayedTask((Plugin) this,

Comment: Okay, so your error should make sense... `(Plugin) this` where `this` is a `Commands` **not** a `Plugin`

Comment: That's what happens when you rush something, you forget to call the Main class.. oopsies. Thank you so much for helping push that to my mind! Appreciated surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> at com.ShlobdonG.gMarry.Commands.onCommand(Commands.java:182)

`scheduleSyncDelayedTask((Plugin) this`

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ShlobdonG.gMarry.Commands cannot be cast to org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin

Makes sense, right?

`public class Commands` is probably not extending / implementing the `Plugin`